# Arff file nominal value not declared in header

Tags: artificial-intelligence, weka, arff

I am trying to load an Arff file that represents letters in binary, it looks like this: http://pastebin.com/zKSr2YJi

But when I try to load it into Weka, I ge the error "nominal value not decalared in header, read Token[A], line 33.

From what I understand from this, the 'A' at the end of the first data line isn't the same as the 'A' in the @attribute class line. But they look the same? I tried adding single quotes, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by copy-pasting the 'A' from the @attribute class line.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be because of trailing paces from this [item](https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Possible-bug-C45-files-not-recognized-td26501.html).
Opening the data file in excel and saving in csv format removes extra whitespace.  Renamed he file as a .data and Weka was able to open.